# Axis2 Exception occurred when trying to invoke service method

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

My webservice is

```
public List getRes(int a, int b) throws Exception { 

List list = new ArrayList(); 

list.add("ddd"); 

list.add("ddd"); 

list.add("ddd"); 

System.out.println(list);
return list;

}
```

I am using axis2 code generator to generate stub.
I am using client

```
HelloWorldStub stublist=new HelloWorldStub();

HelloWorldStub.GetRes requestlist = new HelloWorldStub.GetRes();

requestlist.setA(1);

requestlist.setB(2);

GetResResponse responselist = stublist.getRes(requestlist);

System.out.println("Response : " + responselist.get_return());
```

But this service is throwing exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getRes
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:271)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.execute(OutInAxisOperation.java:202)
at com.HelloWorldStub.getRes(HelloWorldStub.java:246)
at com.Client.main(Client.java:51)
```

Is there any solution for this exception

Thanks in advance

Comment: please indicate which lines the exception is referring to? line 51? if 51 is the second line change HelloWorldStub to stublist.

Comment: yes it's the second line... but it's not workingg with the change suggested

Comment: The problem is that i'm throwing an exception in the web service and in the Web service client a class is generated for that exception beside the stub and the callback... but i don't khnow how to use that class to catch this exception and resolve the problem .... :)